# Executing a stored procedure in vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I'm using the current code to try to execute a stored procedure, and it shows no errors, but the update made by the procedure is not executed.

```vb
Public Function UpdateRouteByRegister(ByVal conexion As String, ByVal idRegister As Integer, ByVal route As String) As Boolean
    Try
        ConnectionString = conexion
        myConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        myDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("spUpdateHistoricLoad", myConnection)
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@idRegister", SqlDbType.Int))
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters("@idRegister").Value = idRegister

        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@route", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100))
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters("@route").Value = route

        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
        myDataset = New DataSet
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataset)
        myDataset.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        Log("******* Register updated = " + idRegister.ToString + " *******")
        Return True
    Catch objException As Exception
        Log("******* Error on updating register = " + idRegister.ToString + " *******")
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The SQL Stored Procedure is the following:

```sql
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateHistoricLoad]
    @idRegister INTEGER,
    @route VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tOperation SET ImagenMulti = @route WHERE IDRegister = @idRegister
END
```

Comment: You tagged this question as `VBA`, but I assume you are using `VB.Net`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'll change it

Comment: The stored procedure, as defined in your post, does not return any records. Is your intent to return data from the stored procedure and fill the dataset, or are you just trying to execute the stored procedure to make the necessary edits?

Comment: @TimLentine, just trying to execute the edits

Comment: Use Sql Server's Profiler to see what actually went to the procedure...may find that you didn't send what you want to send ;-)

Comment: Fixed it, thank you for the suggestion of using Sql Server's Profiler, the problem turned out to be from another conection.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest dropping the DataAdapter and DataSet objects and just use a `SqlCommand`:

```
Public Function UpdateRouteByRegister(ByVal conexion As String, ByVal idRegister As Integer, ByVal route As String) As Boolean
Try
    ConnectionString = conexion
    myConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    myConnection.Open
    Dim cmd as SqlCommand
    cmd = New SqlCommand("spUpdateHistoricLoad", myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idRegister", idRegister)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@route", route)
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    myConnection.Close()
    Log("******* Register updated = " + idRegister.ToString + " *******")
    Return True
Catch objException As Exception
    Log("******* Error on updating register = " + idRegister.ToString + " *******")
        Return False
End Try
End Function
```

Comment: I changed the code to what you suggest, but it sends me an error stating that there is no open conection

Comment: @Throkar I updated the post to include myConnection.Open